# How to remove after login screen (annoyingly slow)?

Tags: login, uninstall, display

I've just installed Ubuntu Server LTS. After login, the screen slooooowwwwwlllllyyyy mutates into a splash screen with a gear and other icons and then sloooowwwwwllllyyyy presents the desktop.

How can I disable/remove this? Seems a lot of wasted time to get to the desktop.

Thanks, Caesar.

Comment: Your probably using KDE (it sounds like it anyway, please specify), you should be able to change this in settings.

Comment: Ubuntu server does not have a log in screen. What DE are you using ?  I agree with @Wilf, sounds like KDE. My advice, use webmin ;)

Comment: Yes it is the stock KDE desktop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how to disable it:
1. Menu -> Settings -> System Settings -> Workspace Appearance -> Splash Screen
2. Choose "None" for Manager for Splash Screen Themes

The next time you login, the annoying post login screen is gone.

Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

The KDE desktop uses quite a lot of effects (transparency, glowing things, blur etc). You should be able to speed up login by disabling the Login splash screen, as well as extra effect under 'Desktop Effects' > 'All Effects', extra services under 'Startup and Shutdown' > 'Seervice Manager', and by reducing resource usage under 'Application Apperance' > 'Style' > 'Fine tuning'.

[This page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/How%20to%20make%20Kubuntu%20%28KDE%29%20blazing%20fast%20and%20optimise%20it%20for%20performance%20|%20kio_http) in the Ubuntu wiki may help, which suggests installing the latest updates and disabling the effects.

As @bodhiz.zazen suggests, using a interface such as [webmin](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/install-webmin-on-ubuntu-14-04-trusty-tahr-server.html) may be better for the running of a server. Another lighter environment (without unnecessary effects) such as [Xfce](https://askubuntu.com/a/65222/178596) or [LXDE](https://askubuntu.com/a/65131/178596) may also work faster.

Comment: I've installed webmin, very useful for remote administration! Also read the KDE performance hints. I've installed Cinnamon instead which is pain free compared to KDE.